# How to update asp:detailsview

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a detailsview in my asp.net project called, it's linked to an asp:datasource. One of the field shouldn't be updated, so i made this field a teplatefield. Despite having checked the option "enable update/delete", the detailsview and datasource remain unchanged when trying to update a record.

I've tried to delete and add the detailsview and sqldatasource. Tried to use ".databind()" on postbacks and on load.

```html
<asp:DetailsView Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" ID="DTSgeg" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="KlantID" DataSourceID="DTSGegevens" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="DTSgeg_PageIndexChanging">

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="KlantID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="KlantID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KlantID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("KlantID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="naam" HeaderText="naam" SortExpression="naam" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="voornaam" HeaderText="voornaam" SortExpression="voornaam" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="gemeente" HeaderText="gemeente" SortExpression="gemeente" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="adres" HeaderText="adres" SortExpression="adres" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="btwnummer" HeaderText="btwnummer" SortExpression="btwnummer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="tel" HeaderText="tel" SortExpression="tel" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AantalAangevraagd" SortExpression="AantalAangevraagd">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AantalAangevraagd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AantalAangevraagd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AantalAangevraagd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />

</asp:DetailsView>
```

I hope that you can help me to find a way so the records can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add one more field under area. For example

```
<asp:CommandField  ButtonType="Button"  ShowDeleteButton="true"  
    DeleteText="Delete Record" ShowEditButton="true"  
    EditText="Edit Record" />
```

Comment: This seems to work, but once i press the update button, i get the error "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Comment: Use ASP.NET Ajax UpdatePanel. (Put the listbox in the Updatepanel and trigger a update, if you add or remove listbox. This way viewstate and related fields get updates and eventvalidation will pass.)